# How to explain GetOptions usage?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I have a script which takes 3 input variables from CLI and insert it to 3 variables respectively:

```
GetOptions("old_path=s" => \$old_path,
       "var=s"      => \$var,
       "new_path=s" => \$new_path,
       "log_path=s" => \$log_path)
or die ("Error in input variables\n");
```

Is there a way in which I can add a subroutine or any other `GetOptions` parameter which explains how to give the input variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way in Perl is to use [Pod::Usage](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html) as recommended in [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).  A complete example is shown in [Documentation and help texts](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Documentation-and-help-texts)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for [Getopt::Long::Descriptive](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong%3a%3aDescriptive).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, we can define HelpMessage subroutine with print statements what we want to show for command help,

```
    GetOptions("old_path=s" => \$old_path,
               "var=s"      => \$var,
               "new_path=s" => \$new_path,
               "log_path=s" => \$log_path,
                "help" => sub { HelpMessage() })
                 or die ("Error in input variables\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. But some correction in the above line:  "help" => sub { HelpMessage() } will be "help" => \&Helpmessage..